# Can you add pie charts to a dashboard in Youtrack 2017.2?

Tags: youtrack

I can create pie charts in Youtrack and I was under the impression that it is possible to add such as widgets to your dashboard, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is this really not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a report for creating a chart widget. In the report options you can change the presentation to pie diagram.

Comment: Right, now I see... Thanks! :)